# Flex 4.6 compiler check if compiling for ios or android

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, compilation, air

I am creating a mobile app for iOS and Android, with flashbuilder 4.6, Flex SDK 4.6.

I am using a ANE for Google Cloud Messaging, which I would like to skip when compiling for iOS. Are there any defines within flashbuilder to check if its compiling for iOS or Android, so i can skip the GCM imports. I don't want to change my compiler defines every time i compile my app.

Another way would be to use an IF statement in the compiler arguments:

```
if (compiling for ios)
    -define+=CONFIG::IOS,true
else
    -define+=CONFIG::IOS,false
```

Is it possible to do something like this, or are there any built-in compiler defines I can use in my code?

EDIT:
package managers has 3 classes:

- NotificationManager.as
- NotificationManagerIOS.as (Singleton for iOS, uses RemoteNotification from Air)
- NotificationManagerAndroid.as (Singleton for Android, uses ANE which does not support iOS)

Compiling for android is fine, compiling for iOS gives errors on the classes from the ANE.

the NotificationManager.as:

```
package managers {
    public class NotificationManager {
         public static function getInstance():NotificationManager {
              var ios:Boolean = (Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf("iOS") != -1);
              if (ios) {
                   return NotificationManagerIOS.getInstance();
              } else {
                   return NotificationManagerAndroid.getInstance();
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found it useful to script the build process with ANT, then the script could set values for the compiler arguments (`CONFIG::IOS,true`) as needed.

Comment: maybe thats an option, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flash Player AVM2 runtime is a virtual machine which uses a [**JIT**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler so what you want to do is not possible.  However, there are 2 common ways to approach this issue:

1. Compile separately for each deployment target, especially if the embedded, OS-specific support files are large.  You can set up your IDE project to contain multiple folders so that compiling for each target is simply opening each folder and compiling the contents.  Read Christian Cantrell's [**Writing multiscreen AIR apps**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/writing_multiscreen_air_apps.edu.html) to see how setting up a project for separate deployment targets can be arranged.
2. If the embedded, OS-specific support files are small, or if you only want to manage one project folder, you can direct the runtime to use the appropriate file by determining its target using [**flash.system.Capabilities**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html):

   `var isIOS:Boolean = (Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf("iOS") != -1);`

   `var isAndroid:Boolean = (Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf("Android") != -1)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using the Capabilities class to instantiate the correct class (a push notification manager for Android and iOS). However, the compiler still reads the Android manager class when compiling for iOS. 

For now, i just compile the projects one by one and remove the classes i don't need, but it would be nicer if i could just compile them both from flashbuilder without having to change anything in code before i compile. I'll take a look at the multiscreen air app you provided